# "Each of you has" vs "Each of you have"

Tags: verbs, pronouns

I had a discussion with a friend about a phrase similar to
"... the perspective each of you **has/have**...".
But we are not sure which form is correct and why. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Close but not identical. In the question you linked me to, I understand the difference between plural/singular. What I wonder is if the verb has to agree with "each", third singular, or "you" second singular, hence my doubt about "has" or "have"

Comment: It's the same question. *Each of you > each **one** of you is, each one of them is, each one of us is.* I imagine more than **one** of those examples **is** going to surprise you. Language is not mathematics.

Comment: "Each" indicates a distributive interpretation, and this is reflected in the selection of a singular head, as in "Each student handed in his work". In your example, "each of you" is a partitive fused determiner-head NP, where fused "you" refers to set x, and "each of you" then means “each member of set x”. Since singular "each" is the subject, singular agreement is normal.

Comment: @AdrianSicaru Are you clear about this now?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I understand now that "each" is the subject so the verb has to agree with it. Much clearer now. Thanks.